# Recording audio and video from different browser tabs simultaneously

Tags: browser, recording, audio-recording, screen-recorder

I'm wondering if there is a way to record screen and audio from different tabs simultaneously; the audio streams should be indipendent. The browser brand is not important.

E.g. if i have 2 tabs (tab1:(audio1, video1); tab2:(audio2, video2)), i need to record the couple (audio1, video1) and the couple (audio2, video2) without mixing them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could launch a virtual machine to accomplish this (i.e. have one tab pair in a browser in a virtual machine).

Short of doing that, I can't think of a simple way to approach this unless someone has written an extension or modified the source code to allow for it.

Comment: Hello @g491 thank you very much for your reply. In general i'd like to record more than 2 tabs, so i need a hosted hypervisor to do that if i've to use a virtual machine for each tab, but it requires a lot of resources. I hope to find a solution more efficient than a hosted hypervisor.